# Make my code wait while a timeline is running

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a blackjack game and I created a timeline that deals a card to the dealer every 1 second to simulate handing out cards. The problem is while this timeline is running the rest of my code continues to run. I need my program to wait until the timeline is completely before continuing.

Here is my timeline:

```
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), event -> {
        if(dealer.getScore() >= 17 && (dealer.getScore() >= player.getScore() || dealer.getScore() > 21)) {
            timeline.stop();
        } else {
            newCard(dealer, mainDeck.deal(), false);
            System.out.println("Running Here!");
            LBLDeck.setText(String.valueOf(mainDeck.getRemaingCards()) + " cards remaining");
        }
    });
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try a CountDownLatch - See docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html